# What is wrong with area?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

Which unit in result of calculating the polygon's geometry programmatically using .Area property of IArea object?

For example, there are 2 polygons. Let's calculate geometry manually (in some projected coordinate system) - two areas are:

3.918650 [sq km]  and 8.984022 [sq km].

Next, I calculate the polygons area programmatically this way

```
        IFeature ftr1 = fc.GetFeature(0);
        IGeometry g1 = ftr1.Shape as IGeometry;
        IArea ar = ftr1.Shape as IArea;
        double strar = ar.Area;
```

The result is:

0.000543 and 0.001243.

[image: Calculate Geometry]

The areas are not proportional in this 2 ways (manual and programmatical):

8.984022 / 3.918650 = 2.292632

0.001243 / 0.000543 = 2.289008

It's very close, but not equal.

using C#, arcgis 10.2.2

Comment: When you say "Let's calculate geometry manually(in some projected coordinate system)", how precisely did you perform those calculations and what projected coordinate system did you use?

Comment: "how precisely" - 10 numbers after decimal point;  "what projected coordinate system" - PCS: Pulkovo 1942 GK Zone 9N (you can see it in edited question post)

Comment: By precisely I just meant the exact steps - with the picture its clear now that you used the Calculate Geometry dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the returned area is in the source projection unit, so in "square degrees".

When you computed it manually, you first reprojected your layer to the dataframe coordinate system.

To get the proper result, you will have to either reproject the whole layer, or, in ArcObjects, to project the individual polygons before reading their area.

And last, since a degree does not have the same length in meters in latitude as in longitude, the computed area is meaningless, and that's why the ratio between the 2 areas is different.